# Delete statement in iphone not working

Tags: iphone, sql, ios, sqlite, ios5

I am deleting all data from the table by using below code snippet

```
NSString *deleteStatementNS = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"DELETE FROM %@",[tableNames objectAtIndex:i]];

const char *prepareDelete ="DELETE FROM '?'";
const char *tbleName = [[tableNames objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dBase, prepareDelete, -1, &dbpreprdstmnt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
{
    dbrc = sqlite3_bind_text(dbpreprdstmnt, 1, tbleName, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    dbrc = sqlite3_step(dbpreprdstmnt);

    sqlite3_finalize(dbpreprdstmnt);
    dbpreprdstmnt = NULL;
} 
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Error %@",[NSString stringWithCString:sqlite3_errmsg(dBase) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
}
```

But unfortunately the delete is not happening I am getting error as `Error no such table: ?`
I am not able to prepare the statement only. But if i use prepare statement like below

```
const char *prepareDelete =[deleteStatementNS UTF8String];
```

This is working absolutely fine. I am not able to bind the variable to stop SQL injection attacks.May I know the reason behind this error please. I found many places where this code snippet is reported as its is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not able to bind the variable to stop SQL injection attacks.

Table names cannot be bound as variables.

To avoid SQL injection attacks don't let your users specify which table names will be deleted. Make sure the table names come from a trusted source (e.g. hardcoded in your program).

In fact it's a really bad idea to delete all data in a table when the table name comes from an untrusted source. Even if you prevent SQL injection attacks, an attacker could still delete data you didn't want them to delete.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I am getting table names from other SQL query and it'll be stored in the array in runtime. All table names are dynamic so i guess no problem in using it. And, I am aware that no one cant make his app completely secure from hacker. But for curiosoty how a hacker can still hack my DB or how he can still do injection attacks if I bind the variables. Will you please educate me on this please.